The product of the alternating lengths of a hexagon whose vertices belong to an ellipse
About 6 years ago, I came up with a wonderful ellipse property, and I did not prove it and forgot about it, but now I remembered it
I put my question here in order to get proof, and also to know if this property is known in advance.
We have a hexagon whose sides touch an ellipse and then we reached the contact points to form another hexagon, and we connected the opposite vertices in the large hexagon to divide the sides of the small hexagon into parts, so the alternating parts will be equal in both cases, look at the picture:

In fact, this property generalizes for any polygon that touches an ellipse and has an even number of sides and its main diagonals intersect at one point.

amazing intuition you had

First of all, it is enough to prove the property in a circle. That's because we can always apply an affine transformation to squish the ellipse into a circle:

The affine transformation will not change the ratios of lengths of collinear segments, so proving the property after the transformation is enough to prove that the property was already true before the transformation.
For notation, let's say that the center point where the diagonals intersect is $P$. Let the vertices of the external polygon (in green in the diagram) be $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_{2n}$; let the tangent points of lines $E_1 E_2, E_2 E_3, \dots, E_{2n} E_1$ be $T_1, T_2, \dots, T_{2n}$, respectively; let the intersection of $T_{i-1}T_i$ with $PE_i$ be $X_i$. So we are trying to prove that $$\frac{T_{2n}X_1}{X_1T_1} \cdot \frac{T_1 X_2}{X_2 T_2} \cdots \frac{T_{2n-1} X_{2n}}{X_{2n} T_{2n}} = 1.$$
First, turn this into a ratio of areas: $T_{i-1}X_i : X_i T_i = [PT_{i-1}E_i] : [PE_iT_i]$, where $[ABC]$ denotes the area of $\triangle ABC$. So our product becomes $$\frac{[PT_{2n}E_1]}{[PE_1T_1]} \cdot \frac{[PT_1E_2]}{[PT_2E_2]} \cdots \frac{[PT_{2n-1}E_{2n}]}{[PE_{2n}T_{2n}]}.$$
Second, we can shift the numerators over by one step, to turn our product into $$\frac{[PT_1E_2]}{[PE_1T_1]} \cdot \frac{[PT_2E_3]}{[PE_2T_2]} \cdots \frac{[PT_{2n}E_1]}{[PE_{2n}T_{2n}]}.$$ In this new product, each ratio $[PT_i E_{i+1}] : [PE_iT_i]$ is the ratio of two parts of the the triangle $\triangle PE_iE_{i+1}$ divided by the line $PT_i$. These areas are in the same proportion as the line segments $T_iE_{i+1}$ and $E_iT_i$, so we can further rewrite our product as $$\frac{T_1E_2}{E_1T_1} \cdot \frac{T_2E_3}{E_2T_2} \cdots \frac{T_{2n}E_1}{E_{2n}T_{2n}}.$$
Finally, we can shift the numerators over again, this time in the other direction. This turns our product into $$\frac{T_{2n}E_1}{E_1T_1} \cdot \frac{T_1E_2}{E_2T_2} \cdots \frac{T_{2n-1}E_{2n}}{E_{2n}T_{2n}}.$$ But in this product, every ratio $T_{i-1} E_i : E_i T_i$ is equal to $1$, because these are two external tangents to the circle from the same point, $E_i$. So the final form of the product is a product of $1$'s, which is equal to $1$.
